Creating the overlay of buffer polygons in QGIS
I have an outline of forest areas (line) and applied the tool "buffer" to it. Now I want to create a file that only contains the overlay of the buffer polygons.
In ArcGIS Pro this can be done with the tool "intersect" and add only the buffer-layer to the input. Is this possible in QGIS?
